# Name 'false' is not defined when adding "justMyCode": false to launch.json in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I was just trying to debug my program in python in which I have a third party library (written always in python) that doesn't work as expected.

My launch.json file is:

{

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": false
    }
  
]
```

}

But it gives me the error:

**Name 'false' is not defined**

as soon as I start debugging the problem.

Can someone help me please?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 27):

This configuration triggers the run or debug of the currently focused file (see the *"name": "Python: Current File"*, and *"program": "${file}"* settings) And the error message popups, because you tried to debug launch.json file - which makes no sense for a python debugger.

In other words - first, you have to switch to/focus your python file and trigger debug afterward.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem!!

Comment: Another way is to set `"program": "main.py"`, if you want to debug `main.py`

Comment: I re-opened a project I haven't looked at in a month at got this. I read your answer and thought, wow I can't believe I did that!